# how can I print details (table name, column name, data type) of each column/table in my db2 database?

Tags: sql, db2

[In my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729447/how-can-i-print-results-from-sql-procedure?noredirect=1#comment103833060_58729447) Mark suggested a good answer for displaying count on every table in my database. I would like to expand this procedure and - instead of counts - display the specific info (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE) about each column in the database.

I so far have the following command:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EXPORT_SCHEMAS()
RETURNS TABLE (P_TABSCHEMA VARCHAR(128), P_TABNAME VARCHAR(128), P_COLUM_NNAME VARCHAR(128), P_DATA_TYPE VARCHAR(128))
BEGIN
  DECLARE L_STMT VARCHAR(256);
  DECLARE L_ROWS VARCHAR(256);

  FOR V1 AS
    SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME
    FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
    WHERE TYPE = 'T'
    ORDER BY 1,2
  DO
    SET L_STMT = 'SET ? = (SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE FROM SYSIBM.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = "'||V1.TABNAME||'" AND TABLE_SCHEMA = "'||V1.TABSCHEMA||'")';
    PREPARE S FROM L_STMT;
    EXECUTE S INTO L_ROWS;
    PIPE(L_ROWS);
  END FOR;
  RETURN;
END@

SELECT * FROM TABLE(EXPORT_SCHEMAS())@
```

but now when I run it:

```
db2 -ntd~ -f export_schemas.sql > dump.csv
```

I'm getting the error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL20019N  The result type returned from the function body cannot be assigned
to the data type defined in the RETURNS clause.  LINE NUMBER=17.
SQLSTATE=42866
```

Could you please help me and let me know what is wrong here and how could I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't you be better of by directly querying a join between COLUMNS and TABLES, sorted by tabschema / tabname and column number?

Comment: could you give me some example of such query? Thanks!

Comment: What's your Db2 version and platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Db2 for LUW, then you shouldn't use `SYSIBM` schema in your queries on the system catalog. Use `SYSCAT` instead.

You don't have to use any functions to get what you want here. Use the following query instead:

```
SELECT TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, COLNAME, TYPENAME
FROM SYSCAT.COLUMNS
ORDER BY TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, COLNO;
```

As for your routine. There is a number of errors in the text.

1) if you want to assign multiple values with `SET` statement, you must use the corresponding number of parameter markers in the statement:

```
SET (?, ..., ?) = (SELECT COL1, ..., COLn FROM ...);
PREPARE S FROM L_STMT;
EXECUTE S INTO L_V1, ..., L_Vn;
```

2) `RETURNS TABLE (...)` and `PIPE(...)` must have the same number of columns

Answer (score 0):

You could directly query the tables [SYSCAT.COLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001038.html) and [SYSCAT.TABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html). The following returns the table schema and name followed by column name and their type. Column info is sorted by the column order:

```
select t.tabschema, t.tabname, c.colname, c.typename, c.colno
from syscat.columns c, syscat.tables t
where t.type='T' and t.tabname=c.tabname and t.tabschema=c.tabschema
order by 1,2,c.colno
```

BTW: Db2 has a tool [db2look](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) to export schema information.